# AMAZON EDI / required payer name in NAD+IV segment is longer than 35 character limit

Tags: sap-erp, edi, edifact

I am working for a big manufacturer and supplier to Amazon. We are currently in testing mode with them for EDI. We are using AS2, EDIFACT standard, like required from Amazon. regarding INVOIC messages, Amazon is insisting on a specific payer address in NAD IV segment - the company name of Amazon Germany, which is about 41 characters. We have exact payer address stored in SAP, but once we make EDI transfer, the payer name segment is cut to 35 character.

**What we can transmit:**

```
NAD+IV+5450534005838::9++AMAZON EU SARL:NIEDERLASSUNG DEUTSC+Marcel-Breuer-Str. 12+MUENCHEN++80807+DE'
```

**What AMAZON expects:**

```
NAD+IV+5450534005838::9++AMAZON EU SARL:NIEDERLASSUNG DEUTSCHLAND+MARCEL-BREUER-STR. 12+MUENCHEN++80807+DE
```

Amazon is consequently rejecting our invoices after transmission as long as there is no exact match.It is insane, as Amazon itself provides documentation where the field limit is stated.

However we do not get qualified response over their vendor central. (Everyone working with Amazon knows what I mean)
Has anybody experience with EDI setup with Amazon, their requirements and this specific field limitation?

We have tried to use an abbreviation of company name, but this is not accepted. Billing address cannot be changed.
Change of field length in code not possible at the moment

Comment: Not really a programming question! Don't you want to ask this question at Super User instead? Please paste the segment with spaces because it's impossible to compare with the standardized positions. Note that the NAD has only 35 characters-long address fields, not 41...

Comment: it is somewhat remotely connected to programming, as it is, as far as I can see, a misunderstanding of the EDIFACT syntax.

Answer (score 3):

the NAD segment has several name and address fields in composite C080 (5 of them in release D96A in fact). You can store the required name in those fields, not just in the first one. The colon in your message example is **not** part of the name, it is a **separator** for fields in a composite. It's part of the EDIFACT syntax. The plus sign separates fields and composites, the colon separates fields within a composite.

dissecting the expected NAD segment it looks like this:

- `NAD` (Segment name)
- `IV` Field 3035, Party Qualifier
- `5450534005838` Composite C082, Field 3039, Party Identification
- Composite C058 is left empty
- `AMAZON EU SARL` Composite C080, Field 3036 (**first** occurrence), Party Name
- `NIEDERLASSUNG DEUTSCHLAND` Composite C080, Field 3036 (**second** occurrence), Party Name
- `MARCEL-BREUER-STR. 12` Composite C059, Field 3024 Street
- `MUENCHEN` Field 3164, City Name
- Field 3229 is left empty
- `80807` Field 3251, Postcode
- `DE` Field 3207, Country coded

I personally use the EDIFACT directories from Truugo to check the message definitions:

- the NAD segment: https://www.truugo.com/edifact/d96a/nad/
- the INVOIC message https://www.truugo.com/edifact/d96a/invoic/

Comment: To clarify Dirk's correct answer a little, each of the sub-elements of C080 have 35 character limits, and `AMAZON EU SARL` and `NIEDERLASSUNG DEUTSCHLAND` are 14 and 25 characters respectively.